# gputools install failed - "Unknown option 'framework'"

Tags: r, cuda

I've struggling to install the `r` package `gputools` on my machine. I've installed CUDA and set the correspoding PATH files correctly as said [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gputools/INSTALL).

When compiling the package I initially got the error

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -gencode arch=compute_10,code=sm_10 -gencode arch=compute_13,code=sm_13 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -c -I. -I"/usr/local/cuda/include" -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.0/R.framework/Resources/include" -m64 -Xcompiler -fPIC rinterface.cu -o rinterface.o
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_10'
```

I solved this by removing the `-gencode arch=compute_10,code=sm_10` from the `gputools` makefile (found this simple solution [here](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/mailing_list/vmd-l/24562.html)).

Now it compiles some stuff for about 30 seconds and then ends with the following error:

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -gencode arch=compute_13,code=sm_13 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -shared -m64 -Xlinker '-rpath /usr/local/cuda/lib -F/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.0/R.framework/Resources/.. -framework R' -L"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.0/R.framework/Resources/lib" -L"/usr/local/cuda/lib" -lcublas -framework Accelerate rinterface.o mi.o sort.o granger.o qrdecomp.o correlation.o hcluster.o distance.o matmult.o lsfit.o kendall.o cuseful.o -o gputools.so
nvcc fatal   : Unknown option 'framework'
make: *** [gputools.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘gputools’
* removing ‘/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.0/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/gputools’
```

The complete console output can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/paulklemm/d79344a86baf6dbed805). I'm lost on this one, there is only one occurence of `-framework` in the `config.mk` file, which is `R_FRAMEWORK := -F$(R_HOME)/.. -framework R` and even removing `-framework R` doesn’t make a difference.

Note: I use `R CMD build gputools && R CMD INSTALL gputools_0.28.tar.gz` to compile it from the repo as [recommended here](https://github.com/nullsatz/gputools/wiki/Install)

Has anybody an idea what I could try?

Comment: Have you figured this out?  I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, but I could not figure out a solution for this problem. Hope you find a way to get this to work.

Comment: @rimorob I was able to fix this problem on my machine. Just leaving a comment so you're notified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [gputools 1.0](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gputools/index.html) has solved my issue. I've been able to install it without problems using `R 3.2.2`.

```
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin15.0.0                
system         x86_64, darwin15.0.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.2                         
year           2015                        
month          08                          
day            14                          
svn rev        69053                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
nickname       Fire Safety
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. I'm posting this as a solution, but I don't have enough reputation to comment. Paul, your solution worked for me. My device is a GeForce GT 750M with 3.0 CUDA capability.

I downloaded the last source gputools_0.28.tar.gz and decompressed it. Then I modified line 19 in src/Makefile:

```
NVCC := $(CUDA_HOME)/bin/nvcc -gencode arch=compute_10,code=sm_10 -gencode arch=compute_13,code=sm_13 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30
```

to look like this:

```
NVCC := $(CUDA_HOME)/bin/nvcc -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30
```

finally, installed with

```
R CMD INSTALL gputools
```

where gputools is the folder created after decompressing the source.

My R version is

```
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin13.4.0                
system         x86_64, darwin13.4.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.2                         
year           2015                        
month          08                          
day            14                          
svn rev        69053                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
nickname       Fire Safety
```

Comment: I tried the solution. For my `R 3.1.2` installation, the error remains the same.  I've upgraded to the latest version `R 3.2.2`, but the install errors due to a failed md5 checksum on the makefile. Did you bypass the md5 check in some way? Please find the updated logs in this gist: [https://gist.github.com/paulklemm/d79344a86baf6dbed805](https://gist.github.com/paulklemm/d79344a86baf6dbed805)

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same "framework" error and was finally able to fix the problem. Allow me to start from the beginning. If you are getting a compile error about `Unsupported gpu architecture`, you can fix this by first extracting the package

```
tar -xzvf gputools_0.28.tar.gz
```

then edit the Makefile

```
vi gputools/src/Makefile
```

to the more recent architecture flags for the new nvidia compiler

```
-gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20
-gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30
-gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35
-gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50
-gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52
-gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52
```

You can find more details about this on [NVidia's website](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/maxwell-compatibility-guide/#axzz3op6C2Z3H). Remove any that continue to give compile errors.

Then put the tar.gz back together and try to install it

```
tar -czvf my_gputools_0.28.tar.gz gputools
R CMD build gputools && R CMD INSTALL gputools_0.28.tar.gz
```

Don't forget the environment variables that are talked about in the [package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gputools/INSTALL)

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda/5.0
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/5.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
```

At this point, if you get a `Unknown option 'framework'` exception, it seems that the nvcc command line parameter has changed slightly. Look again in the makefile and look for `${shell R CMD config BLAS_LIBS}`. This is the part that was inserting the `-framework <value>` parameter for me. You can test for your configuration by just running the command `R CMD config BLAS_LIBS`. The new command to include frameworks is

```
-Xlinker -framework,<value>
```

There is more information at this [Nvidia page](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/455799/-framework-with-nvcc-and-or-objective-c-/)